# Unresolved class com.microsoft.identity.client.BrowserTabActivity

Tags: java, android, outlook, authorization, azure-ad-msal

So I was following the tutorial on this site https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-android to try to integrate outlook authentication but my manifest doesn't recognize `com.microsoft.identity.client.BrowserTabActivity` which is part of step 3. I tried including `'com.microsoft.identity.client:msal:0.3.+'` in build.gradle but it has its own sets of problems so I avoided that.

A thing to mention, initially the entire `microsoft.identity.client.BrowserTabActivity` was unrecognizable but now it's just the `BrowserTabActivity` class itself that the manifest is not able to find.

If anyone can explain a solution to this or provide an alternative for an outlook login in an app, that would be great.

When msal was implemented in the build.gradle file, it gave the following error

> ERROR: In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library
>   dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[1.3.1
>   ,2.3]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited
>   by the library will be unknown.
>
> Dependency failing: com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:5.7 ->
>   net.minidev:json-smart@[1.3.1,2.3], but json-smart version was 2 .3.
>
> The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or
>   have transitive dependencies that lead to the art ifact with the
>   issue.
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.microsoft.identity:common@{strictly 0.0.10-alpha}
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.microsoft.identity.client:msal@0.3.+
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.microsoft.identity.client:msal@{strictly 0.3.1-alpha}
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto net.minidev:json-smart@{strictly 2.3}
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt@{strictly 5.7}
>
> For extended debugging info execute Gradle from the command line with
>   ./gradlew --info :app:assembleDebug to see the dep endency paths to
>   the artifact. This error message came from the google-services Gradle
>   plugin, report issues at https://
>   github.com/google/play-services-plugins and disable by adding
>   "googleServices { disableVersionCheck = false }" to your b uild.gradle
>   file.

Comment: hi, have you managed to resolve the issue?

Comment: did you managed to solve this issue?

Comment: I think you shoud avoid "avoiding to include 'com.microsoft.identity.client:msal:0.3.+'" :D
I managed to solve the issue by simply adding the 'com.microsoft.identity.client:msal:0.3.+' package to buid.gradle